# Why am I getting inf on controlled calculation?

Tags: python, cpython

I have a function that has a loop, inside of which I do both division and multiplication. The final answer is easily representable, as should the running answer be.

```
def tie(total):
    count = total / 2
    prob = 1.0
    for i in xrange(1, count + 1):
        i_f = float(i)
        prob *= (count + i_f) / i_f / 4
    return prob
```

-

```
tie(4962) == 0.01132634537589437
```

but

```
tie(4964) == inf
```

Is the compiler trying to do some optimization, doing the arithmetic operations in an order other than I seem to have specified and that order is supposedly equivalent but causes the overflow?

Comment: add the following line to your loop: "print("({} + {}) / {} / 4".format(prob,count,i,i))" and you will see what is going on

Comment: I added a third solution to my answer that may suit you better than either the integer-based one or the `lgamma`-based solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running into issues because even though the *final* result of your `tie` function should mathematically be between `0` and `1`, the *intermediate* values in your loop grow very large: for `total = 4962`, the value of `prob` halfway through the iteration is around `1.5e308`, which is *almost* but not *quite* large enough to overflow a Python `float`. For `total = 4964`, the mid-way value really *does* overflow a `float`, and since `inf` times anything finite is still `inf`, the `inf` from the overflow propagates all the way down to the final value.

If you're prepared to accept a (fairly small) amount of floating-point error, there's no need to compute this quantity using a loop at all: you can use the [`lgamma`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/math.html#math.lgamma) function from the `math` module to compute the log of the relevant factorials. (You could also use the `gamma` function directly, but that would likely also lead to overflow issues.)

Here's a version of your function based on this.

```
from math import lgamma, log, exp

def tie(total):
    count = total / 2
    return exp(lgamma(2*count + 1) - 2*lgamma(count + 1) - count*log(4))
```

Alternatively, you could compute the 2n-choose-n term using pure integer arithmetic (which won't cause overflow), and only produce a float at the last moment (when dividing by `4**count`). This will be less efficient that the above, but will give you (in a sense) perfect accuracy, in that it'll give the closest representable float to the exact answer. Here's what that version looks like:

```
from __future__ import division

def tie(total):
    count = total // 2
    prod = 1
    for i in xrange(1, count+1):
        prod = prod * (count + i) // i
    return prod / 4**count
```

Note: the floor division in `prod * (count + i) // i` may look wrong, but it actually works: a little bit of elementary number theory shows that at this point in the calculation, `prod * (count + i)` must be divisible by `i`, so it's safe to do an integer division.

Finally, just for fun, here's a third way to compute your probability that's similar in spirit to your original code, but avoids overflow: the value `prob` starts at `1.0` and steadily decreases to the final value.

```
def tie(total):
    count = total // 2
    prob = 1.0
    for i in xrange(1, count+1):
        prob *= (i-0.5) / i
    return prob
```

Besides being immune from overflow issues, this solution will be more efficient that the integer-based solution, and more accurate than the `lgamma`-based one.

Answer (score 1):

`prob` grows to be quite large and eventually overflows.  Given the name, did you intend `prob` to always be between 0 and 1?

Comment: The function returns prob. For 4962, it returns a number between 0.01 and 0.02. Yes, it is a probability. Why do you say it grows very large?

Comment: Ah, thank you. I suppose if I started from the back, I would get underflows. I guess I need to start in the middle (3/4 * count and 1/4 * count) and work toward both 0 and 1/2 and 1/2 and 1 (all * count). Or dynamically check whether the number is getting too big or to small and owrk in the other direction for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Your prob variable grows very large and for total equals 4964 it overflows Python maximum float value [sys.float_info](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.float_info)

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.float_info.max)
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

Comment: The function returns prob. For 4962, it returns a number between 0.01 and 0.02. Why do you say it grows very large?

Comment: Apparently it dosen't. Let't do the math: Each time you multiply by (count + i) / i / 4. Count is 2481 and i is 1,2,3,... for the first rounds you multiply by 2482/4, 2483/8, 2484/12, 2485/16 ... so prob increases every round. It takes quite a while until that fractions gets smaller than 1 and prob starts decreasing again.

Comment: @Shubit: What's being computed *is* a probability: the final result is between `0` and `1`. The issue is that intermediate results are overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "controlled calculation"? What causes the overflow is `prob` getting bigger and bigger.

Comment: I meant that I iteratively both divided and multiplied in an (insufficient) attempt to keep the numbers manageable.

The simplest expression of this calculation would overflow for much smaller inputs (around 110).